# Elasticsearch - how to upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, magento-upgrade

Recenlty, I upgraded my Magento from v.2.4.1 to 2.4.2.
The process went smoth with no issues.

As Magento v2.4.2 supports Elasticsearch v7.9.x I would like to upgrade my curently installed 7.6.x to 7.9.x.

Can I kindly ask you to give me a tip on how to upgrade it?

The shop is stil a project so don't mind taking it temporarily offline.

Could I just stop the elasticsearch with
`sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service`
and then then install the newer version with the following:

`wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.3-amd64.deb`
`wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.9.3-amd64.deb.sha512`
`shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-7.9.3-amd64.deb.sha512`
`sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.9.3-amd64.deb`
and finaly start the servise with

`sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service`

Thank you in advance.

My enviroment: Magento 2.4.2, Apache, php7.4, elasticsearch7.6

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this link. It has a detailed explaination
https://sysgears.com/notes/upgrade-elasticsearch-on-linux/